# Angular Reactive Forms form control valueChanges stops listening on error

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a registration form where I am using `valueChanges` listener on a form control and makes call to http service that posts to server if this value already exists, e.g. email and user name. If the value exists already on the server, then a status code 403 is returned. I am catching and handling this error by presenting a message to the user, but my problem is the `valueChanges` listener stops listening, so if I just change the form value, then this code is idle. Can I get the listener to continue even after the error? Should I be handling this another way? Thank you.

Here is listener code:

```
    this.watchEmailSub = this.registerForm.controls.email.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(v =>
        this.regService.checkRegistrationValueExists('Email', v, this.registerForm.controls.email.valid)
      )
    ).subscribe(returnValue => {
        this.registerEmailError = null;
        console.log('returnValue.message = ', returnValue.message);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.warn('Error = ', error);
        this.registerEmailError = 'This email already exists';
      }
    );
```

HTTP service code:

```
  checkRegistrationValueExists(type: string, value: string, formControlValid: boolean): Observable<any> {
    // Code removed here that defines checkValueExistsUrl & checkValueExistsBody
    if (formControlValid) {
      return this.http.post<string>(checkValueExistsUrl, checkValueExistsBody);
    }
    return of({ message: `${type} invalid` });
  }
```

Comment: That how observables acts.
Once they hit an error they stop listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use catchError and swallow the error to prevent this:

```
this.watchEmailSub = this.registerForm.controls.email.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(v =>
    this.regService.checkRegistrationValueExists('Email', v, this.registerForm.controls.email.valid).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.registerEmailError = 'This email already exists';
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )
  )
).subscribe(returnValue => {
    this.registerEmailError = null;
    console.log('returnValue.message = ', returnValue.message);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.warn('shouldn't be here');
  }
);
```

IMO 403 shouldn't be thrown here.  403 is inapropriate in any event, as 403 means unauthorized to view this information, if any error, it'd be a 400. Beyond that though, this is an API endpoint specifically checking availability. Error codes mean something went wrong. Nothing went wrong here, it checked and returned your answer successfully, yes it exists or no it doesn't.

Comment: thanks - I wondered about 403 code as well. I could easily handle this if no error code was returned and just use the `returnValue.message` value. Even using the catchError operator the `valueChanges` listener appears to stop unfortunately.

Comment: sorry, had the catchError in the wrong place. need to catch it inside the switchMap

Comment: another side note... this might be better as an asyncValidator anyway.

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution is working for me! I will look into asyncValidator as well. I actually pass the formControl validation status to my http service, so in fact if the formControl is not valid, then there is no http call to server. asyncValidator may be cleaner way of doing the same thing.

Comment: asyncValidators always run after sync validators, so yea, that'd be built in.